# Apk acting like it doesn't have landscape variation

Tags: android, updating, landscape-portrait

I'm doing a app with 3 Activities, when I run the apk to test, the first activity runs fine in portrait mode and landscape mode, but the second and the third one runs a little wonky, so I created a landscape variation for every one and fixed all the display problems, but when I run the apk now, once again the first one is fine, but the second and third one doesn't update to the new landscape variations and still shows the wonky one... I tried to rebuild, clean, and didn't work...

Android Studio 2.3.3

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.omfgdogs.omfgapostas">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/mei"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/mei"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Main3Activity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Check your manifest file, have you used configchanges or any additional in manifest file's activity tab?

Comment: Put your manifest file here.

Comment: Done, I used the configchange so the activity dont reset the data when the variation changes..